# How to view data from database (REST)

Tags: android, android-studio

[Bottom navigation SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlLDC.png)I already done bottom Navigation in my app using android studio. So, I would like to create a button in one of my fragments. How can i do it? Any video references? Thank you.

Comment: Hi First your question title or description are too different, and another thing to implement what you want to implement, For that you need to take core knowledge of Android which you help better than direct jump.
And easily you can implement what you want.

Comment: I am sorry for my unrelated title and desc because i cannot submit the title that I initially post before. Actually my main thing is that later I want to get some data from db using REST. However, I need to create a button that can be clicked in the fragment first (Refer image). For example click "PRESENT" will view the data . So how is it possible to do the button inside fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so easy not much harder just put your button in your fragment layout then after creating the instance in your fragment and put listener for that particular button like bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/mBtnPresent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FragmentTest extends Fragment {


    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        AppCompatButton mBtnPresent=view.findViewById(R.id.mBtnPresent);
        mBtnPresent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //perform action what you want on button click
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Now, I want to know whether it is possible to do REST connection in the fragment? I would like to pull out some data from database into that fragment. Before this I have tried to pull out data from mysql, it works. But this time, I want to make my database private. Thus, I need to use REST method. So how could it possible?